# Delete some page numbers

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

How can I delete page numbers from only some pages? I've got some large figures which go over the margins, and have the page number superimposed.

Comment: Just my opinion, but if at all possible i would edit the picture in such a way that the page number is not included, even it means simply taking a little square out of the picture. Much easier when page numbers change etc, you won't need to worry about the pagenumber being correct.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Unless you're typesetting a magazine, I think your document will read better if you make the figures fit within the margins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a empty pagestyle for a specific page:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

Comment: Shouldn't one use the `empty` page style to remove page numbers?

Comment: Of courese `\thispagestyle{empty}`.